# Redirect file url to another page in .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I need to redirect all php files from end of urls to a specif dir like:

```
http://example.com/dir/file.php 
http://example.com/dir/folder/file.php 
http://example.com/dir/folder/folder2/file.php
```

to

```
http://example.com/dir2/file.php
```

my code is

```
RewriteRule ^(.*).php$ http://example.com/dir2/$1.php [R=301,L]
```

but I'm getting

```
http://example.com/dir2//dir/file.php
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, please do add your tried htaccess rules in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following :

```
RewriteRule ^.*/?([^/.]+).php$ http://example.com/dir2/$1.php [R=301,L]
```

This will just capture `/file.php`  in the regex and not the directory.

Comment: This regex are getting only the last character from filename, how can i get all name?

Comment: @MarcosVinicios I have updated the pattern.

Comment: @MarcosVinicios  Your welcome ! Glad I could be of help. . (Thnx so much!!❤️❤️)